# Spring Boot CookieLocaleResolver - set supported locales

Tags: spring-boot

I'd like to set supported locales for `CookieLocaleResolver`. The `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` has methods for this. But CookieLocaleResolver seems to accept any valid languages from the cookies.

I am using this code:

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        var localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver("LANG");
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver acceptHeaderLocaleResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setSupportedLocales(List.of(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.GERMAN));
        acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        localeResolver.setDefaultLocaleFunction(acceptHeaderLocaleResolver::resolveLocale);

        return localeResolver;
    }
```

The AccepptHeaderLocaleResolver works as expected and falls back to Locale.ENGLISH if the Browser Language is not in the list of supportedLocales.

However if I set the LANG-Cookie to a unknown language (i.e. "af") this unknown language will be used anyway.

Is there a way to set supported locales for the CookieLocaleResolver as well?

I would expect that I can set supported locales for CookieLocaleResolver similar to AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver

Comment: Change your expectations for the `CookieLocaleResolver` that isn't possible. Simply because it wouldn't make sense. You could change the locale and for that you would need the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`, which would only be triggered by a selection (etc.) from the front-end which would be controlled by you. There is no way, currently to set the supported locales on the `CookieLocaleResolver`. But it is pretty easy to add it yourself if you desire.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see your point. Maybe my case is more special than I expected. There are other front-end apps which use the same language cookie but might have other translations available.

Comment: Even if the `Locale` is set to something that isn't usable, if you don't have a special localized message file it will fallback to the default one (this is done in the `MessageSource` implementations.